# Highcharts showLoading at the beginning

Tags: javascript, highcharts, loading-animation

I am trying to show the loading text or an animation when my page opens, but somehow it doesn't work and I am not getting wiser from this explanation: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Chart.showLoading
I have also checked various examples with a button, but unfortunately it also did not work for me. This is a snippet from my code:

```
<script>
            $(function () {
                chart.showLoading('Loading data ...');
                $.getJSON('http://url/data_1/', function (data) {

                    // define and process data
                    var ohlc = [] ;
                    ohlc.push([...]);
                    ...
                    }

                    // create the chart
                    var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
                        plotOptions: { ... },
                        series: [{ ... }],
                        });
                    });
</script>
```

I very much appreciate any help.

Comment: try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/members/chart-show-hide-loading/) example. Hope it will work for you

Comment: showLoading method requires a chart to be instantiated before the method is used - you do the opposite.

Comment: @morganfree Thank you. But if I create the chart first with ´var chart = Highcharts;´ it still doesn't work. Also Thank to Saurabh. Your example works with a button after the chart was created and the data was loaded, but unfortunately I still can't get it to work WHILE the data is loading without clicking a button